# Cannot connect to virtualbox, after installing Docker

Tags: networking, macos, virtualbox, docker

I have a virtualbox guest that I used to work on and had no trouble logging in via ssh over vboxnet0. Recently I installed Docker and it created vboxnet1.

Now I cannot ping my guest machine anymore. Other than installing Docker I did not do anything to mess with my network settings in any way.

I cannot ping either way. When checking with `ip a` and `ifconfig` respectively I get that the guests IP is `192.168.56.101` and vboxnet0 has IP `192.168.56.1`. When activating the guests NAT network it connects to the outsideworld withouth problems.

Changing the guests adapter to vboxnet1 also made no difference.

My host machine is a macbook, I am using all the latest releases of all the included software packages. The virtualbox guest is running ubuntu 16.04 lts.